# Return a value to a text input field from php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

I've got a dropdown field in php from a table with a list of workcodes.  After the workcode is selected i need to lookup the rate from another table depending on the workcode and input this into a input field.  So in the workcode dropdown I've got the onchange event to execute the javascript.

In the Javascript I execute rate.php but how do I get the value in rate.php back to field?

**The workcode dropdown:**

```
//workcode drop down
        $get5 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM va_workcodes order by BriefDesc");
        $option_wc = "<select name='wc' id='wc' onchange='getrate()'>";
        while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($get5)) {
        $option_wc .= "<option value = '";
        $option_wc .= $row5['WCNo'];
        $option_wc .= "'>";
        $option_wc .= $row5['BriefDesc'];
        $option_wc .= "</option>";
        }
        echo $option_wc;
        echo "</select>";
```

**The rate field**

```
echo "<input name='rate' id='rate' type='text' />";
```

**The javascript/jquery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getrate(){
    $.get("rate.php");
}
</script>
```

**rate.php**

```
<?php
$getrate1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rates where .....");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($getrate1)) {
  $StdRate = $row1['StdRate'];
}
?>
```

**So basically I need to return *$StdRate* from rate.php to the inputfield (rate)**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code:

**rate.php**

```
<?php
$getrate1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rates where .....");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($getrate1)) {
   $StdRate = $row1['StdRate'];
}
echo $StdRate;   // Print the rate in the end
?>
```

**javascript/jquery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getrate(){
    $.get("rate.php", function(data) {   // Add a callback to success and retrieve printed value as parameter
        $("#rate").val(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

The problem was that you were making an AJAX call, but not returning it's result, which I have done by printing, also after returning you have to consume that result which I have done in JS by creating a callback function.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I did it exactly as you sugestested.  I can see the echo of $StdRate if I test rate.php but it is still not returning it to the input field.

Comment: can u tell me exactly when does the input field appear in your HTML. Is it after AJAX, or it's always there just the value has to be filled after AJAX call.

Comment: I made a mistake with the jquery `value` function, it should actually be `val`. Please make a not of same and let me know if it still doesn't work...

Comment: Awesome that was it.  I will go through your scripts now and try to understand it since I only know php and not js or ajax.

Comment: I'm glad to help. You can find tons of resources in regard to AJAX, I would recommend going to [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) and looking it up...